# Multiply variables with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to multiply fields `order['count']` and `product.price`

```html
{% for product in product %}
    <td class = "price">{{ product.price }}</td>
    <td>
        <input class="count form-control" style="width: 40%" type="text"
             {% for order in basket %}
                 {% if order['id'] == product.id %}
                     value="{{ order['count'] }}"
                 {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}
         />
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

How I can do it with jQuery?

My html

```
<div>
  <table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Count</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td><input value="2 /></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Under what event are you trying to do this?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the generated html?

Comment: There is also no jquery here - maybe you mean HTML? Or Javascript? Or Jinja2?

Comment: @mprat i want do this operation with jquery,

Comment: To do any operation in jQuery you need to write code attached to an event. That may be DOM ready, click for example. Please specify your requirement in detail.

Comment: Also by your comment "multiply order['count'] and product.price" do you mean do that for every combination?  By your annotations it looks like you could have multiple entries of this due to the for each

Comment: @Taplar i refresh question

Comment: @Taplar yes, i need each function to multiply proper quantity and price

Comment: You are still missing a few key elements for this question to be good: 1) When do you want to calculate this? On page load? When the user clicks update? When it's noon o'clock? 2) Where does this data go? Your table shows 2 columns. Do you want this in a 3rd? 3) Do you have class or id tags for your HTML?

Comment: @Adam Link when page load. In some div

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go off of the assumption that you want to do this for every one of them.  You can filter down if this is not what you want.  Also going to do it without an event so if you want it to happen on an event you'll have to derive the bindings.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.price').each(function(){
        var $price = $(this);
        var $count = $price.parent().find('.count');

        console.log( +($price.html()) * +($count.val()) );
    });
});
```